# Scala function which computes a stream that contains an Arithmetic sequence

Tags: scala

**Test**

```
test("arithmetic") {
  assert(Calculation.arithmetic(5, 10) === 30)
}
```

**Main**

```
def arithmetic(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = {
  val c = b - a
  val third = b + c
  val fourth = third + c
  val fifth = fourth + c
  fifth + c
}
```

In Scala one could create [a stream that contains a Fibonacci sequence](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_14.html) using `val fibs = fibFrom(1, 1).take(7)`. Is it possible to use a stream that creates `Arithmetic` sequences in Scala as well? If positive, how to implement it?

Comment: But that fibs Stream already is an arithmetic sequence. So I don't see what you are asking for.

Comment: I am looking for a stream that generates e.g. `5, 10, 15, 20, 25 and 30` instead of `1,1,2,3,5,8`. I thought that the first is an `arithmetic` and the latter a `fibionacci` sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fibonacci sequence is an arithmetic sequence and you can create whatever sequence you want:

```
scala> val s: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: s.map(_+5)
s: Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> s(10)
res0: Int = 50

scala> (s take 10).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45)
```